# Junit console runner doesn't detect tests

Tags: java, kotlin, junit

I'm trying to launch all my tests via junit-platform-console-runner.

Tried some simple commands like:

`java -jar C:\git\autotesting\junit-platform-console-standalone-1.5.2.jar -cp C:\git\autotesting\target\test-classes --exclude-engine junit-vintage`

Tried command from other discussions like:

`java -jar C:\git\autotesting\junit-platform-console-standalone-1.5.2.jar --class-path C:\git\autotesting\target\test-classes --exclude-engine junit-vintage --scan-classpath`

console-args.txt contains

```
--include-engine
junit-jupiter
--exclude-engine
junit-vintage
--disable-ansi-colors
--details
verbose
--details-theme
ascii
--fail-if-no-tests
--reports-dir
C:/junit5/reports
--scan-classpath
```

But all I got is

```
Test plan execution started. Number of static tests: 0
.
+-- JUnit Jupiter
'-- JUnit Jupiter finished after 6 ms.
Test plan execution finished. Number of all tests: 0

Test run finished after 97 ms
[         1 containers found      ]
[         0 containers skipped    ]
[         1 containers started    ]
[         0 containers aborted    ]
[         1 containers successful ]
[         0 containers failed     ]
[         0 tests found           ]
[         0 tests skipped         ]
[         0 tests started         ]
[         0 tests aborted         ]
[         0 tests successful      ]
[         0 tests failed          ]
```

All tests are @ParametrizedTest